# Vertical Align top two divs not working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Can anyone help me with aligning my two divs? What did I do wrong? I have two inline blocks as my divs and am trying to align them at the highest point of the element side by side.

```
<body>
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a><li>
    </ul>

    <div id="intro">
        <p>HELLO</p>
    </div>
```

css:

```
#navbar {
display:inline-block;
margin-left:25%;
list-style-type:none;
vertical-align:top;
width:12%;
    }

#intro {
display:inline-block;
width:40%;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Can you try to explain a bit more about what you are trying to achive?. Here is the jsfiddle with your code. http://jsfiddle.net/K9K2X/

Comment: Oh sorry I made a huge mistake. http://jsfiddle.net/K9K2X/4/ should link you to the updated one. Im trying to align the yellow box with the blue at the top. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your last closing `<li>` misses the actual closing slash: `</li>`, this might break it on some browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin-top: 0` or any other preferred size (ie `margin-top: 20px;`) to both IDs.

Ex. http://jsfiddle.net/K9K2X/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="navbar">
 <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
 <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
 <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li> <!-- Forgot to close the element -->
</ul>

#navbar li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:25%;
    list-style-type:none;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:12%;
}
```

The links are side-by-side now.

http://jsfiddle.net/K9K2X/8/